# How to export datagrid data to Excel's different sheets?

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I export all of datagrid data to Excel workbook sheet (Sheet1) using these code blocks:

```
private void copyAlltoClipboard()
{
    dataGridView1.SelectAll();
    DataObject dataObj = dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent();
    if (dataObj != null)
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
}
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    copyAlltoClipboard();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    xlexcel = new Excel.Application();
    xlexcel.Visible = true;
    xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Test.xls", Type.Missing, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
    Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
    CR.Select();
    xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);          
}
```

But, I want to export some datagrid rows to another sheet (Sheet2), and remaining rows to another sheet (Sheet3). So, I should separate datagrid data to X pieces. And Excel worksheets count should be the same X and should contain some specific datagrid data. How can I do this?

Comment: Loop through all the cells in the DataGridView and perform all the actions you wish. In case of populating it via DataSource (a DataTable, for example), you might also rely on LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it,

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet1;// defines sheet1
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet2;// defines sheet2
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet3;// defines sheet3
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) // here we add the rest of sheet into the excel
    {
       xlexcel.Sheets.Add(After: xlexcel.Sheets[xlexcel.Sheets.Count]);
    }       
   xlWorkSheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1); //setting the first sheet equal to first sheet in excel
   xlWorkSheet2 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(2);//setting the 2nd sheet equal to first sheet in excel
   xlWorkSheet3 =  (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(3);

//here we add the data to the sheet from datagridview    
    for (int j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet1.Cells[1, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText;
            }
        for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
            {
             for (int j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
                   {
                       DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[j, i];
                       xlWorkSheet1.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = cell.Value;
                   }
            }                      
          xlWorkSheet1.Name = "put name here";
          xlWorkSheet1.Columns.AutoFit();

        for (int j = 0; j <= dataGridView2.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet2.Cells[1, j + 1] = dataGridView2.Columns[j].HeaderText;
            }
        for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView2.RowCount - 1; i++)
            {
             for (int j = 0; j <= dataGridView2.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
                   {
                       DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView2[j, i];
                       xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = cell.Value;
                   }
            }                      
          xlWorkSheet2.Name = "put name here";
          xlWorkSheet2.Columns.AutoFit();   

        for (int j = 0; j <= dataGridView3.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet3.Cells[1, j + 1] = dataGridView3.Columns[j].HeaderText;
            }
        for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView3.RowCount - 1; i++)
            {
             for (int j = 0; j <= dataGridView3.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
                   {
                       DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView3[j, i];
                       xlWorkSheet3.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = cell.Value;
                   }
            }                      
          xlWorkSheet3.Name = "put name here";
          xlWorkSheet3.Columns.AutoFit();  

xlWorkBook.SaveAs("put path here", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
                    xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
                    xlexcel.Quit();
```